# Mixture of Experts - fminunc optimization stopped prematurely

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression

I have a Mixture of Experts code, which works with small number of parameters. It is as follows:

```
global x_au;
global x_vi;
global x_alpha;
global y;
global parameter;

options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'GradObj', 'on', 'Algorithm','quasi-newton','MaxIter', 10000,'Display','iter-detailed'); % change number of iterations
optTheta=[];

x_au=x_au_train;
x_vi=x_vi_train;
x_alpha=x_alpha_train;
y=y_train;
parameter=zeros(8969,1);

%expectation step
fprintf('opt1 begins');
opt_1;
fprintf('opt1 complete');
%maximaization step
[x] = fminunc(@costfunction,parameter(1:4483),options);
parameter(1:4483)=x;
resnorm1=total_error(parameter(1:4483));
k=1;
count = 1;
while(1)
opt_1; 
fprintf('expectation complete');
%maximaization step
[x] = fminunc(@costfunction,parameter(1:4483),options);
parameter(1:4483)=x;
resnorm2=total_error(parameter(1:4483));
fprintf('resnorm1-resnorm2 - %f, resnorm2 - %f, k - %f',resnorm1-resnorm2,0.000001*resnorm2,k);
if((resnorm1-resnorm2)< .000001*resnorm2 & k~=1)  %% to decrease training time 
    break;
end
```

but now, when I have to use this on a problem with a large number of parameters, I get the following log.

```
                                                     First-order 
 Iteration  Func-count       f(x)        Step-size       optimality
     0           1      5.31444e+10                      4.75e+14

Optimization stopped because the objective function cannot be decreased in the 
current search direction. Either the predicted change in the objective function,
or the line search interval is less than eps.
                                                   First-order 
 Iteration  Func-count       f(x)        Step-size       optimality
     0           1      5.31444e+10                      4.75e+14

Optimization stopped because the objective function cannot be decreased in the 
current search direction. Either the predicted change in the objective function,
or the line search interval is less than eps.

resnorm1-resnorm2 - 0.000000, resnorm2 - 53144.356560, k - 1.000000 
                                                    First-order 
 Iteration  Func-count       f(x)        Step-size       optimality
     0           1      5.31444e+10                      4.75e+14

Optimization stopped because the objective function cannot be decreased in the 
current search direction. Either the predicted change in the objective function,
or the line search interval is less than eps.

    resnorm1-resnorm2 - 0.000000, resnorm2 - 53144.356560, k - 2.000000
>>
```

And then the process completes with very bad results. As, can be seen fminunc cannot optimize correctly. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the parameter initialization from zeros to rand and together with normalization, I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reduce training speed coefficient, or normalize you parameters vector.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I tried normalizing that didn't help. First order optimality decreaded to 2.99e+10, but the process still stopped after 3 iterations. What do you mean by reducing training speed coeffcient? Please explain.

Comment: Also, is it reasonable for the model to work with ~9000 parameters for a ~24000 sized dataset?

Comment: I mean that all af these algorithms are near the same: 'x[n+1]=x[n]+alpha * dF/dx'. Seems your  'alpha * dF/dx'  too large. I suggest to reduce alpha. But I don't very good in matlab optimization pack, alpha may be now managed automatically. 9000 parameters may be ok, you need introduce regularization then.